# Why the Jiffy package show the wrong week number

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I see a strange behavior with the `Jiffy` package ([link](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy)). If I run the following code I get the following output (the first is correct, the second is wrong)

> 42

> 43

```
final refDate = new DateTime(2020, 10, 18); // 18 Oct 2020
int weekNumber(DateTime date) {
  int dayOfYear = int.parse(DateFormat("D").format(date));
  return ((dayOfYear - date.weekday + 10) / 7).floor();
}

print(weekNumber(refDate));
print(Jiffy(refDate).week.toString());
```

Can anyone explain when? I see the `.week` function call the same formula... ([link](https://pub.dev/documentation/jiffy/latest/jiffy/Jiffy/week.html))

Thanks!

Comment: You are not the first to notice this: https://github.com/jama5262/jiffy/issues/58

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the intended behaviour of the package, ie weeks to start on Sunday and end on Saturday. Hopefully the developer will give an option to set when the week should start